# android studio taking photos

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

hey i followed a tutorial for taking pictures in an android studios project but my app crashes without any log errors. any help would be appreciated. also if anyone knows how add pictures from the gallery into the imageview that would be great.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button bn;
    int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    ImageView IMG;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bn);
        IMG = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        bn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null){
                    startActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
        });
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data){
        if(requestcode == REQUEST_CODE && resultcode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            IMG.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

HI I suppose you are asking to take picture from gallery or Camera then you want to set that image to ImageView. If i am right then follow below code

```
private void openCamera() {
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH_mm_ss");
String currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), currentTimeStamp);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

}

```
private void openGallery() {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), REQUEST_GALLERY);
```

}

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        try {
            String click = f.getAbsolutePath();
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(User_Detail.KEY_ALBUM_IMAGE_PATH, click);
            values.put(User_Detail.USER_ID, Utlity.user_id);
            values.put(User_Detail.KEY_ID_ALBUM_REF, album_id);
            long loginStat = db.insert(User_Detail.TABLE_4, null, values);
            loadData(album_id);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 } else if (requestCode == 2) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
        picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
        if (picturePath != null && picturePath.length() > 1) {
            ContentValues va = new ContentValues();
        } else {
        }
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String image_path = picturePath;
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(User_Detail.KEY_ALBUM_IMAGE_PATH, image_path);
        values.put(User_Detail.USER_ID, Utlity.user_id);
        values.put(User_Detail.KEY_ID_ALBUM_REF, album_id);
        long loginStat = db.insert(User_Detail.TABLE_4, null, values);
        loadData(album_id);
        c.close();
        Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........", picturePath + "");
    }
}
```

}

**Now You get The ImagePath of selectd Image or Captured Image. Now you need to set in your Image View then Crate a Adapter class which extends BaseAdapter and in that adapter class You can set this image by converting Imagepath to Bitmap**